# Deadlock using Boost condition variables; pointers not updating between threads?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, boost, condition-variable

I'm implementing an application that uses an IO pipeline. I've got three threads, one reading in data (images), one doing some processing on them, and one writing the processed images back out to disk.

I'm running into a deadlock with the reader thread and the processing thread. The threads both have access to a pointer called toDeblur, which is a pointer to the image to be next processed. The reader thread reads in an image, assigns its pointer to toDeblur, and then notifies the processing thread that toDeblur contains an image for processing.

The relevant code for the reader thread is as follows:

```
//Wait until it's okay to read again.
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(*deblurLock);
while(toDeblur != NULL)
{
    readCondition->wait(lock);
}

DeblurImage* read = readImage(is, fileName);

toDeblur = read;

cerr << "readImage notifying deblurCondition" << endl;
//Notify the processing thread(s) that an image is ready.
deblurCondition->notify_one();
```

And the processing thread:

```
//Wait for our condition variable.
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(*deblurLock);
cerr << "processImage waiting for non-NULL image" << endl;
while(toDeblur == NULL)
{
    cerr << "processImage waiting for deblurCondition variable" << endl;
    deblurCondition->wait(lock);
}

readCondition->notify_one();
processImage(kernels, deblurP, toDeblur);
```

However, I've found that when running this code, I run into a deadlock as upon being notified, the processing thread checks if toDeblur is NULL, finds that it is, and goes right back to sleep, yet the reader thread notifies it after it assigns a valid image to toDeblur.

Have I missed something obvious? Is there something I can do to ensure that toDeblur's update is seen by the processing thread?

EDIT: I should add that the snippets above are part of loops, so the locks/waits happen before each round of reading/processing.

The output I get from running the program is as follows:

```
processImage waiting for non-NULL image
processImage waiting for deblurCondition variable
readImage is starting a read
readImage notifying deblurCondition
processImage waiting for deblurCondition variable
```

So processImage wakes up after being notified, but sees that toDeblur is still NULL and goes back to waiting.

Comment: Consider declaring the variable as `volatile` so the compiler doesn't do any optimisations on it.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Sadly, no effect. The problem still happens.

Comment: The goal of your code is pretty unclear. I've pieced together a SSCCE that shows the deadlock in reader thread waiting for toDeblur to become null again: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc3a0ca399b8ecaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The reason for the deadlock is that the toDeblur pointer was being passed to the threads by value, not by reference, which of course meant that when the reader thread updated the value of the pointer, as opposed to the object it pointed to, that update was not reflected in the copy of the pointer that the processing thread had.

Answer (score 1):

Why not queue the 'deblur' image pointers with producer-consumer queues?  You could maybe flow-control it with a fixed pool of *deblur, created at startup and held in a pool queue.

If the processing has more than one thread, you may need a sequence-number in the images to ensure that the output does not get out of order.

Answer (score 0):

You got two conditional variables sharing one lock/mutex, you'd better make each conditional variable companion with an independent lock/mutex. BTW, a typical usage of one conditional variable is:

```
// wait    
while(...){
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(aMutex);
        condVar->wait(lock);
}

// notify
{
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(aMutex);
        condVar->notify_one();
}
```

make sure that lock is released soon after calling wait/notify, otherwise, high possibility lead to dead locking.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it so each thread has its own mutex as well as conditional variable. This doesn't solve the problem, sadly.
I should add that the code snippets above are part of loops, so the locks/waits happen before each round of reading/processing.